# What's the best way to loop this program in python?

Tags: python, loops

```
pyg = 'ay'

original = raw_input('Enter a word:')

if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
    print original    
    word = original.lower()
    first = word[0]
    second = word[1]
    new_word = word + first + pyg  
    new_word = new_word[1:len(new_word)]
    print new_word
else:
    print 'empty'
```

I need this to loop and and when the user inputs 'Quit' with any combination of lower or capital letters. (qUit, QUIT, quIT, i.e.)

any tips are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You've used `str.lower`, so does it still matter whether the input comes with lower or capital letters?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
pyg = 'ay'
original = raw_input('Enter a word:')

while original and original.strip().upper() != 'QUIT':
    # loop body
    if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
        print original    
        word = original.lower()
        first = word[0]
        second = word[1]
        new_word = word + first + pyg  
        new_word = new_word[1:len(new_word)]
        print new_word
    else:
        print 'empty'
    # read again, for next loop
    original = raw_input('Enter a word:')
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
pyg = 'ay'

while True:

    original = raw_input('Enter a word:')

    if original.upper() == 'QUIT':
        break

    if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
        print original    
        word = original.lower()
        first = word[0]
        second = word[1]
        new_word = word + first + pyg  
        new_word = new_word[1:len(new_word)]
        print new_word
    else:
        print 'empty'
        break
```

Answer (score -1):

new_word = new_word[1:]

## it's better!

#to split the first word

nom = 'AlassaneAli'

mylist = list()

for i in nom:

```
    mylist.append(i)
```

for a in range(len(mylist)):

```
print(mylist[a])
```

print(mylist[1:])

Comment: That doesn't answer the original question at all. Are you sure you meant to answer this question, and not some other one?